# ASP.net onClick not handling Eval correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick, eval

I've got a  with an onClick event in it to link to another page with an id pulled from the listview row that is clicked.

```
<div class="LVitem" onClick="location='Links.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>'">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The Eval works in the ItemTemplate to fill the listview but does not seem to return anything when used in the onClick event.

What I see in the browser is:

```
<div class="LVitem" onClick="location='Links.aspx?id='">
```

I've seen a number of references to the use of single and double quotes and have tried to change them but it's complicated with the Eval within the location within the OnClick.  I also tried this but it actually returned nothing, not even the "Links.aspx?id=" string.

```
<div class="LVitem" onClick='<%# Eval("id", "Links.aspx?id={0}") %>'>
```

Would really appreciate a hand with this one.  Thanks all.

Comment: The last version works for me. Are you sure that "id" thing is spelled correctly? Can you show the code for the dataitem class

Comment: Ugh...it's always obvious after the fact.  I had the onClick in the Layout Template, not the ItemTemplate.  Going to close this.

Comment: Here is some advice - use the ItemDataBound event in the code behind instead of Eval. Just cast the sender to the appropriate type (can't remember right now, you can check in the debugger) and use FindControl to find the control you want to bind to. Then you can use normal statically typed C# to set the values. The only downside is that if you change the structure of the item template you will need to change the code behind to get the appropriate control